# OpenCart functional questions switching from Magento 1.9?

Tags: opencart

First off I must apologise if this question is not bringing juice to the table.

I've been using Magento 1.9 and don't like the idea of going to Magento 2. Looking at OpenCart 3 as a solution to the problem, but has been difficult to find answers to a couple of questions.

The major issue is, I ship all over Europe. Currently, I have a checkout cart Total Weight of products value.
The buyer enters a country or Zip/Postcode, my external PHP function determines the Postal Zone / Region from that data and so generates a Post Price. The Post Price calculation is as an external PHP function included into Magento.
How easy would this be to implement in OpenCart 3?
e.g. 3 Products (8Kg) sending to the UK (which is determined as Zone 3) Therefore, Zone 3 weight range of 5kg to 10kg cost = 14.00 euros.

Can the Checkout sequence be removed therefore letting the buyer Click PayPal checkout only? i.e. don't want customers to create accounts etc. This is very difficult to do in Magento.

Is the Confirmation Email template configurable regarding layout and content, plus an automatic generation of the order number?

How easy is to initially bulk import products with associated images, and update said products by exporting and re-importing without affecting any of the product data history? A nightmare in Magento.

Thank you and sorry again if this has been covered elsewhere.

Barton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The major issue is, I ship all over Europe. Currently, I have a
>   checkout cart Total Weight of products value. The buyer enters a
>   country or Zip/Postcode, my external PHP function determines the
>   Postal Zone / Region from that data and so generates a Post Price. The
>   Post Price calculation is as an external PHP function included into
>   Magento. How easy would this be to implement in OpenCart 3? e.g. 3
>   Products (8Kg) sending to the UK (which is determined as Zone 3)
>   Therefore, Zone 3 weight range of 5kg to 10kg cost = 14.00 euros.

Opencart has weight-based shipping module so you can try to work it out using zones and weight

> Can the Checkout sequence be removed therefore letting the buyer Click
>   PayPal checkout only? i.e. don't want customers to create accounts
>   etc. This is very difficult to do in Magento.

The checkout sequence can be modified if needed if you have programming knowledge or you can use extensions or modifications from the opencart store

> Is the Confirmation Email template configurable regarding layout and
>   content, plus an automatic generation of the order number?

You can edit the templates or content of emails by editing the code, the order number is automatically generated.

> How easy is to initially bulk import products with associated images,
>   and update said products by exporting and re-importing without
>   affecting any of the product data history? A nightmare in Magento.

There's no option for import in opencart but you can try extensions or modifications for this from the Opencart store

You can download and try it yourself to understand it better. Here is the demo site link for opencart:

[demo.opencart.com](http://demo.opencart.com) and [demo.opencart.com/admin](http://demo.opencart.com/admin/)